# How to to authenticate before route change in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react, react-router (version 2.8.1).
I want to authenticate user before it route to next URL.

How do i achieve this?

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
            <Route path="ticket" component={Ticket}/>
        </Route>    
        <Route path="profile" component={Profile}>
            <Route path="create-user" component={CreateUser} />
        </Route>    

    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Comment: did you find any solution @Raj Rj

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this in my routes:

```js
<Route
      component={ PageContainer }
      path="page"
      onEnter={ requireAuth }
/>
```

Comment: onEnter={ requireAuth }
where to write requireAuth() function?